# ASP.NET MVC - return View("MyView"); crashing application. How can i debug that?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

So, today i went back to some old methods in my application that i wrote in the past to discover, that when i execute "`return View("MyView");`", it crashes my application. Chrome just keeps loading and loading and nothing happens. It worked perfectly in the past, i didn't change a thing in that. How can i debug that and know what is happening? I execute some other stuff before returning a view, but a breakpoint successfully passes through this return and then nothing happens. :-O

Comment: What do you see in Fiddler?

Comment: Wow. That was fast. I am not using fiddler, i want to debug this from a visual studio? Also i don't think it's my program fault, i think it might be more of a visual studio web developer server, so i would prefer to see some logs from within, but i dont know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I've experienced this problem, it has always been due to a problem with FormsAuthentication. The loop is usually a redirect to the login page because the page detects you aren't logged in but the login page redirects back because it detects you are logged in.

The usual cause is using another app for authentication but the keys used by the two apps (specified in the machineKey setting) don't match.

Comment: That's exactly what i discovered right now! This is a werid bug, have you managed to fix it? Do you remember how?

Comment: Check the machineKey settings in the web.config file. They need to match between the two apps.

Comment: No, i don't use any "two apps", so i don't have any machineKey defined. I need to look further into that bug. :-/

Comment: You can use a site like http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/generatemachinekey/ to generate the MachineKey with random key values.

Comment: Is your logon page in the same path as the page experiencing the problem? If not, do either of the paths include a child web.config? That can make IIS treat it as a separate app.

Comment: Well my MyView.cshtml is just a shared view in my main folder of views, not connected to any controllers, while my logon page is just /home/index, and today i changed that logon page from the default one. So probably ure right. So what do i need to do? Add machine keys to both of my web.config files? Will try it right now.

Comment: When i add this whole machinekey to my web.config file it doesnt recognize it. :/

Comment: Did you put it in the system.web element?

Comment: No, i put it in <configuration> section. I guess thats my bad. but anyways, i already discovered what was causing the error. It was looping through login() method, but not because i had two apps, it's because i had a simple "hack" i used in my site, and modelbinder went full retard on this one. I described the problem just now in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162990/asp-net-mvc-how-to-execute-exact-action-using-razor-helper-html-action