# ASP.NET MVC - how to execute EXACT action using razor helper Html.Action();

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have something like this:

```
class AccountController : Controller
{
   [HttpGet]
   public ActionResult Login()
   {...}

   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
   {...}
}
```

Now, this is difficult to explain:
With every request that is sent, i check if user is authenticated, if not, i display a login window for them within my page. I display it by executing: `@Html.Action("Login", "Account", new {})` And this action usually returns a partialView, so i can put in within my page.

Now i explain problematic use case: When user registers himself, he sents me back register data, when this register data somehow is bad and i detect it in my controller, i am sending this data back to the user so he can correct himself. When i do this, i re-render page sent to the user and by doing that i execute `@Html.Action("Login", "Account", new {})` for the second time. But this time i have user data in memory. So model binder thinks, that i didn't request [HttpGet] Login() method, but it tries to execute [HttpPost] version. Now i think that the best is to change names of both of those versions of this action. But maybe there is some kind of magic that allows me to keep the same names and to execute exactly what i wanted to without letting modelbinder to decide?

Comment: I think it could be the empty route value object.  Try getting rid of `new{}` in the `Action` call and see what happens.

Comment: Actually i added new{} to erase any route data. Without new{} it gives the same result